# Calculation between two inputs and result in another

Tags: javascript, jquery

The script below works only for the first block when you enter the quantity.

Is there any way the function performs the calculation depending on the block in which the quantity is entered.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.somente-numero').keyup(function (e) {
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
 var v1 = Number(document.getElementById("v1").value);
    var v2 = Number(document.getElementById("v2").value);
    var v7 = document.getElementById("v7").value = parseFloat(v1 * v2).toFixed(2);
 });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bloco 1 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_org]" id="v1" size="10" value="100.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][quantidade]" id="v2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_total_prod]" id="v7" size="10" readonly />

<br>

<!-- bloco 2 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_org]" id="x1" size="10" value="200.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][quantidade]" id="x2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_total_prod]" id="x7" size="10" readonly />

 <!-- bloco 3 -->

 .................

 <!-- bloco n -->
```

Comment: There is no clear demarcation between blocks, you need to put them in different containers.

Comment: You can check input id and then perform the calculation. You can do: $(this).attr('id') == 'desired-id'

Comment: @Marco, thanks for your feedback but I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update your code with this script.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.somente-numero').keyup(function (e) {
                var currentVal = $(this).val();
                var replaceD = currentVal.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
                $(this).val(replaceD);
                var v1 = Number($(this).prev().prev().val());
                var v2 = Number($(this).val());
                var calculatedval = parseFloat(v1 * v2).toFixed(2);
                $(this).next().next().val(calculatedval);
            });
      });
```

Comment: You should put $(this) in a var to cache it. You'll enjoy great performance jump.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your common block under a common class (say, `.bloco`). Then just find the closest `.bloco` and find `.input1`, `.input2`, `.input3`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.somente-numero').keyup(function (e) {
   $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
   $elBloco = $(this).closest('.bloco');
   var v1 = Number($elBloco.find('.input1').val());
   var v2 = Number($elBloco.find('.input2').val());
   var v7 = $elBloco.find('.input3').val(parseFloat(v1 * v2).toFixed(2));
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bloco 1 -->
<div class="bloco">
    <label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero input1" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_org]" size="10" value="100.00"/> 
    <label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero input2" name="produto_solicitado[0][quantidade]" size="10"/> 
    <label>total</label> <input type="text" class="input3" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_total_prod]" size="10" readonly />
</div>

<br>

<!-- bloco 2 -->
<div class="bloco">
    <label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero input1" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_org]" size="10" value="200.00"/> 
    <label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero input2" name="produto_solicitado[1][quantidade]" size="10"/> 
    <label>total</label> <input type="text" class="input3" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_total_prod]" size="10" readonly />
</div>
 <!-- bloco 3 -->

 .................

 <!-- bloco n -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, only javascript updated:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.somente-numero').keyup(function (e) {
 $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,''));
 var _id = $(this).attr('id');
    var result = 1.0;
    $('input[id^='+_id.charAt(0)+']').each(function(i, el){
     if ($(el).val().length != 0){
        result *= Number($(el).val());
     }
 });
 result = parseFloat(result).toFixed(2);
 $('#'+_id.charAt(0)+'7').val(result);
 });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bloco 1 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_org]" id="v1" size="10" value="100.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[0][quantidade]" id="v2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[0][valor_total_prod]" id="v7" size="10" readonly />

<br>

<!-- bloco 2 -->
<label>preço</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_org]" id="x1" size="10" value="200.00"/> 
<label>quantidade</label> <input type="text" class="somente-numero" name="produto_solicitado[1][quantidade]" id="x2" size="10"/> 
<label>total</label> <input type="text" name="produto_solicitado[1][valor_total_prod]" id="x7" size="10" readonly />

 <!-- bloco 3 -->

 .................

 <!-- bloco n -->
```